# F# flickering createGraphics

Tags: f#

Hi i have problem with async drawing on Panel. If i dont clear it works but with clear it is flickering all time long. I create Form and Panel in main loop but I want to draw in game loop. My problem is how to draw on Graphics panel without having flickering

```
let rec gameLoop (gamePanel:Panel) (lastTime:int64) (ball:Ball) =  async {
    lock gamePanel ( fun() ->
        if gamePanel.IsDisposed || close then
            ()
        else
            let rectangle = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(100, 100, 200, 200);
            use graphics = gamePanel.CreateGraphics();
            graphics.Clear(Color.White) (* when i use this it flickers *)
            graphics.DrawEllipse(System.Drawing.Pens.Black, rectangle);
            graphics.FillEllipse(ball.brush(), ball.rectangle());
    )
    return! gameLoop gamePanel (lastTime) (ball.move())
}
```

edit x2. Flickering still exists but maybe i am on good way

```
type PanelF() as this=
        inherit Panel()
        do this.DoubleBuffered <- true
        member this.setStyle(a,b) = this.SetStyle(a, b)
```

edit x3. I added System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(30) it works better but still not quite what i wanted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do

```
do this.DoubleBUffered<-true
```

In the constructor of your form.  This will enable double buffering which stops flickering by rendering to a hidden buffer and swapping buffers once rendering is done.

Here is a full answer in the idiomatic F# style (using `class ... end` is not common`)

```
type PanelF() as this=
        inherit Panel()
        do this.DoubleBuffered <- true
        member this.setStyle(a,b) = this.SetStyle(a, b)
```

Comment: @Luffy - did you read my anser - you need to put `this.doublebuffered<- true` in the constructor, not as a member.

Comment: I can't set this in constructor. I got invalid expression.

new() = {inherit Panel(); this.DoubleBUffered <- true}

Comment: I got that this is invalid expression on the left side. It means that
this.DoubleBUffered <- true is incorrect